# why is the datetime in database different when I output it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

In my database on heroku, it shows contactemail.created_at = "2010-08-08 17:16:19"

However, when I use puts.contactemail.created_at I get something different.  I get:

2010-08-08 10:11:13 -0700

I need to input that value through an API to another application, and I am pretty sure that the first format is what it wants.  If it doesn't take that, it wants 08/08/10 17:16:19 -- in either case, I don't know how to format it properly.

This is in Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The display of date is based on your servers locale settings. If you are looking for the first format you could try

```
puts.contactemail.created_at.to_s(:db)
```

Have a look at `strftime` doc here http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.html#M000298 to get the second format

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Ruby on rails can manage different time zones.

You can:

- Make a direct sql consult (rails have some helpers)
- Make that the two dates be equals, configuring [config.active_record.default_timezone](http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/howtos/time-zones)